# How to reconfigure code to output specific values rather than collection

Tags: vb.net, browser, html-agility-pack

I currently this code on my app that works great to loop through a page and grab the label of an input value of a form and then print the value to a rich text box.

I am now trying to revamp the code to give me the ID the value if the label contains a specific name.

For instance if the label before the input field contains the word Username then I want the application to output the ID of the input field rather than just everything that has a label.

Here is my current code:

```
    Dim web As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = web.Load("http://shaggybevo.com/board/register.php")

    Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection
    ' Keeps track of the labels by the associated control id     

    Dim labelText As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
    ' First, get the labels     

    nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//label")
    If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node In nodes
            If node.Attributes.Contains("for") Then
                Dim sFor As String
                ' Extract the for value                 
                sFor = node.Attributes("for").Value
                ' If it does not exist in our dictionary, add it                 
                If Not labelText.ContainsKey(sFor) Then

                    labelText.Add(sFor, node.InnerText)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input")

    Dim sbText As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)
    If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node In nodes
            ' See if this input is associated with a label             
            If labelText.ContainsKey(node.Id) Then
                ' If it is, add it to our collected information                 
                sbText.Append("Label = ").Append(labelText(node.Id))
                sbText.Append(", Id = ").Append(node.Id)
                sbText.AppendLine()
            End If
        Next
    End If




    RichTextBox1.Text = sbText.ToString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to change the if statement in the last loop to:

```
' See if this input is associated with a label             
If labelText.ContainsKey(node.Id) Then
    Dim sLabel As String

    sLabel = labelText(nodeId)

    ' If it is, see if the label name is one that we are looking for
    If sLabel.IndexOf("username", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 OrElse sLabel.IndexOf("user", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 OrElse sLabel.IndexOf("u", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
        ' Report the node associated 
        Console.WriteLine("Username is associated with node id " & node.Id)
        ' And bail out of the loop
        Exit For
     End If
End If
```

Comment: To the rescue again. Thanks competent_tech :)

Comment: Sorry...I spoke too soon..This isn't what I was looking for. What I'm trying to do is have the app do..if the label contains the any of the words in ("Username") ("User") or ("U") then grab the id of the input field. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to show you what you need to do.

Comment: Man your on it...sorry to keep bugging you on this bit of code...I'm learning I promise...

Comment: What if you wanted to get several input id's than just the one labels inner text? Let's say there are 3 labels...label #1's inner text is Username, lable #2's inner text is Password, and label #3's text is Email.  I'm not able to get the code to loop through and place each one into the richtextbox.

Comment: Figured it out!!! I just copy the above text you gave me for each label inner text that I wish to capture.. Thanks